# Can a Tastypie filter be applied to a detail resource?

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a Django model with a `sequence_number` field that is incremented each time the model instance is updated:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.TextField()
    sequence_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I have implemented a Tastypie resource for this model, like so:

```
class FooResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Foo.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'foo'
        list_allowed_methods = ['get']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['put', 'get']
```

So a client user can request a particular instance of Foo using an URL like this:

```
http://.../api/foo/123/
```

Clients applications retain the `sequence_number` so they know which version of the object they are holding.

I want to implement a filter on the detail resource so that a client can pass the `sequence_number` they are holding to the server:

- If someone else has updated the object since the client's last request (so the server sequence_number will be greater than client sequence_number) then the resource should return the updated object.
- If the server sequence_number is unchanged, then the resource should return nothing (or empty fields etc.).

I tried to implement this by adding a filter to the resource meta:

```
    filter = {
        'sequence_number': ('gt',),
    }
```

And using the following url:

```
http://.../api/foo/123/?sequence_number__gt=123
```

But it had no effect.  it did work when I used the list resource i.e.

```
http://.../api/foo/?sequence_number__gt=123
```

So - is it possible to configure Tastypie to accept filters on detail resources?  If not, any suggestions as to how I should roll my own solution (while still using Tastypie)?

Comment: I'm not sure if its possible/how to filter on a detail view. Could you not use the list view, using http://.../api/foo/?id=123&sequence_number__gt=123 (maybe with limit/order set as well) then if none match the list returned will be empty otherwise it will show the latest entry?

Comment: Good suggestion but it would get rather messy for my exact use case.  In practice I'm not using the id in the URL. I'm passing two other fields (one of which is from another model) which together form a compound key, like this: `http://.../api/foo/field1/field2/`. I then use prepend_urls to convert them to the id field.

Comment: I've found one option. In `dehydrate` I can access the query params like this `sequence_number = bundle.request.GET.get('sequence_number__gt', None)`.  I can compare this with `bundle.data['sequence_number']` and munge the data I'm returning to the user where necessary.  Not very elegant, though.

Comment: Ah OK i see. I think your best bet then would be to look at overriding something like obj_get on your Resource, so you can check for sequence_number in request.GET - https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L2117 ...

Comment: ...that being said, I'm not sure that method would be any cleaner then your last comment.